# How do I exit a loop?

Tags: loops, 6502

I am creating a simple program that allows the user to type input, and then exits the program when the user enters a certain key. However, I'm not sure where to go with the code I currently have below:

```
            OBJ $8000
    KYBD    EQU $C000
    STROBE  EQU $C010
    COUT    EQU $FDED
    HOME    EQU $FC58

    START   JSR HOME
    LOOP    LDA KYBD
            CMP #$80
            BCC LOOP
            STA STROBE
            JSR COUT
            JMP LOOP
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like you already know how to do comparisons and conditíonal branches. That should be enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, just test the contents of .A for the keycode you want to use to exit, and then branch if equal:

```
        OBJ $8000
KYBD    EQU $C000
STROBE  EQU $C010
COUT    EQU $FDED
HOME    EQU $FC58

START   JSR HOME
LOOP    LDA KYBD
        CMP #$80
        BCC LOOP
        CMP #$<KEYCODE>
        BEQ EXIT
        STA STROBE
        JSR COUT
        JMP LOOP
EXIT    NOP
```

Answer (score 2):

The addresses and keyboard strobe behaviour look like an Apple II, so I'll use that to answer. (If this is actually a retrocomputing question then you could post it over on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).)

For a slightly different take from Eight-Bit Guru's answer, here's a version ("A") of your code that assumes you want to print the end key character (since it's often Enter/Return as below) which makes the loop end cleaner. You can also omit the CMP #$80 because LDA KYBD sets N.

```
START   JSR HOME
LOOP    LDA KYBD   ;Key pressed?
        BPL LOOP
        STA STROBE ;Yes: clear key
        JSR COUT   ;Print key
        CMP #$8D   ;End key?
        BNE LOOP
        RTS        ;Yes: return to caller
```

If you don't want to print the end key, you should still clear the strobe before exiting:

```
START   JSR HOME
LOOP    LDA KYBD   ;Key pressed?
        BPL LOOP
        STA STROBE ;Yes: clear key
        CMP #$8D   ;End key?
        BEQ EXIT
        JSR COUT   ;No: print key
        JMP LOOP
EXIT    RTS        ;Yes: return to caller
```

The exit code will be specific to the environment. For instance RTS would be fine if it was called from Applesoft BASIC with CALL 32768, but if your program had been called from the ProDOS Disk Operating System you would need to call an API with the QUIT command.

Note that version "A" only works if COUT preserves the contents of A, as it does in the Apple II firmware. Keeping in mind what's in each register and what flags are changed or left untouched after each instruction is the way to concise and compact assembly language.